# Arduino EEPROM store multiple data

Tags: arduino, c, eeprom

I just need a small help to completed my project. As my output is printing 2 result but only 1 output is saving to the eeprom. How can I save multiple data into eeprom? I'm just showing the setup and loop only cause the rest is not that important.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hit 'y' and RETURN, if you want to calibrate...");
  Serial.println("Hit 's' and RETURN, if you want to collect data...");
  Serial.println("Hit 'x' and RETURN, if you want to clear the cal data in EEPROM...");
  Serial.println("If not, 'n' and RETURN");
  Serial.println(' ');
  Serial.println("\n");
  keyResponse=readkey();
  //keyResponse='n';
  if (keyResponse=='y'){
      calibration();
  }
   if (keyResponse=='s'){
      Serial.println("Collecting data...................");
  }
  else if (keyResponse=='x'){ 
    while (!eeprom_is_ready()); // Wait for EEPROM to be ready
    cli();
    calData.written=0;
    eeprom_write_block((const void*)&calData, (void*)0, sizeof(calData));
    Serial.println("Cal data is cleared...");
    sei();    
  }
  else {
     while (!eeprom_is_ready()); // Wait for EEPROM to be ready
     cli();
     eeprom_read_block((void*)&calData, (void*)0, sizeof(calData));
     sei();
     if (calData.written==99){
       Serial.println("Using previously stored cal data from EEPROM");
       output[0]=calData.dx; output[1]=calData.dy; output[2]=calData.dz;
       output[3]=calData.dv; output[4]=calData.dd;
     }
     else {
        Serial.println("no previous cal data, using default");
     }
    data();
    exit(0);
  }
  readAcc(ValueX,ValueY,ValueZ,'x',10);
  gXA = mapAcc(ValueX, midX, sensX); //cannot let gXA at 0, will create err.
  gYA = mapAcc(ValueY, midY, sensY);
  gZA = mapAcc(ValueZ, midZ, sensZ); 
  GNA = norm(gXA,gYA,gZA); 
  preTime=micros();
}
void loop() {

int i=0;
  while(loopI<=2){
 // read the both analog in values:
            readAcc(ValueX,ValueY,ValueZ,'x',10);
curTime=micros();
dT=curTime-preTime;
preTime=curTime;
aT=aT+dT;
gX = mapAcc(ValueX, midX, sensX);
gY = mapAcc(ValueY, midY, sensY);
gZ = mapAcc(ValueZ, midZ, sensZ);

LPF(gX,gXP,gXA,gXins);
LPF(gY,gYP,gYA,gYins);
LPF(gZ,gZP,gZA,gZins);
gNins=norm(gXins,gYins,gZins);
cap(gNins,0.01,1);

gXinsA=(gXinsA+gXins)/2;
gYinsA=(gYinsA+gYins)/2;
gZinsA=(gZinsA+gZins)/2;
gNinsA=(gNinsA+gNins)/2;

GN = norm(gX,gY,gZ);
LPF(GN,GNP,GNA,GNins);
cap(GNins,GNlowB,GNhighB);
GNinsA=(GNinsA+GNins)/2;

Max(gNinsMax,gNins);
Max(GNinsMax,GNins);

reset_vel(gNins, gNlowB, vel);
reset_vel(GNins, GNlowB, VEL);

vel=vel+9.81e-6*gNins*dT;
VEL=VEL+9.81e-6*GNins*dT;
act_dist=act_dist+9.81e-6*vel*dT;
act_DIST=act_DIST+9.81e-6*VEL*dT;

actCnt=actCnt+1;

if (actCnt>=10){
actGN=sqrt(actGN_acc/10);
actGN_acc=0;
actgN=sqrt(actgN_acc/10);
actgN_acc=0;

dist=dist+act_dist;  act_dist=0;
DIST=DIST+act_DIST;  act_DIST=0;
actCnt=0;
}
actgN_acc=actgN_acc+(gNins*gNins);
actGN_acc=actGN_acc+(GNins*GNins);

dispCnt=dispCnt+1;
if (dispCnt>=40){
display_result(0);
loopI++;

dispCnt=0;
}
gXP=gX; gYP=gY; gZP=gZ;  GNP=GN;
  }         
output[0] = gXins;
output[1] = gYins;
output[2] = gZins;
output[3] = VEL;
output[4] = DIST;
  Serial.println("Cal data written to EEPROM..."); // store to EEPROM   
  calData=(calData_t){99 , 0,0,0,0,0,0,output[0],output[1],output[2],output[3],output[4]};
  while (!eeprom_is_ready()); // Wait for EEPROM to be ready
  eeprom_write_block((const void*)&calData, (void*)0, sizeof(calData));

 if(loopI>2)
 {   
   exit(0);
 }
}
```

Updated:

```
  else {
     while (!eeprom_is_ready()); // Wait for EEPROM to be ready
     cli();
     eeprom_read_block((void*)&calData, (void*)(i* sizeof(calData)),sizeof(calData));
     sei();
     if (calData.written==99){
       Serial.println("Using previously stored cal data from EEPROM");
       output[0]=calData.dx; output[1]=calData.dy; output[2]=calData.dz;
       output[3]=calData.dv; output[4]=calData.dd;
     }
     else {
        Serial.println("no previous cal data, using default");
     }
    data();
    exit(0);
  }
```

Comment: I'm not clear of the problem. You save `calData` to the eeprom starting from address 0 , if you want to store another copy you can save it to another address that is at least `sizeof(calData)` higher. So if the size of `calData` is 20 bytes then the first copy will occupy eeprom address 0-19 and you can write the second copy to eeprom address 20-39

Comment: can u show me some example to store first copy and second copy? how about if i loop 10 times, will i able to store ten copy into EEPROM?

Answer (score 1):

The method I'm suggesting is something like

```
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        eeprom_write_block(&calData, i*sizeof(calData), sizeof(calData));

}
```

As an example, if the `sizeof(calData)` is 10bytes then the 10 copies will be written to the following eeprom address:

```
0*10 = 0 
1*10 = 10 
2*10 = 20 
3*10 = 30 
4*10 = 40 
5*10 = 50 
6*10 = 60
7*10 = 70
8*10 = 80
9*10 = 90
```

Comment: I have one question. how to i add this in my code. eeprom_busy_wait() someone suggest me to use this instead of loop.

Comment: @FufuAlex You can add a variable i that increments in each write (`i++`) and when it reaches 10 you can set it to 0 again. The  `eeprom_busy_wait()` is not needed, refer to  [this post](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=341112#341112)

Comment: i add this method `for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  eeprom_write_block((const void*)&calData, (void*)0+(i* sizeof(calData)),sizeof(calData));` but i got an error `EEPROM.ino: In function 'void loop()':
EEPROM:488: error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic`

Comment: @FufuAlex use `eeprom_write_block((const void*)&calData, (void*)(i* sizeof(calData)),sizeof(calData))`

Comment: Thanks. no more error but i cant display my previous result. do i need to make some changing in my `void setup()`?

Comment: @FufuAlex I did a test with an array and it is written 10 times in sequential locations of the eeprom (as expected). To read the values you have to use a similar way using eeprom_read_block and reading from location (i* sizeof(calData) where i is 0-9

Comment: ok i have made the change according to what u say, like using a similar way as eeprom_read_block. as i notice, it overwrite the first data.

Comment: @FufuAlex eeprom_read_block reads data from the eeprom so what do you mean when you say it overwrites data? Overwrites data in eeprom?

Comment: if u look at the picture, it display 2 result then `cal data wriiten to EEPROM...` So that mean it only store the second result. it should be display first result then `cal data wriiten to EEPROM...` then follow by second result then `cal data wriiten to EEPROM...`